# Dynamicly add items to ListBox via Attributes

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

i've got 3 classes (all deriving from the same base class) and i have to dynamicly fill a ListBox with the Property-Names.

I've tried like this

```
class Test : TestBase {
    [NameAttribute("Name of the Person")]
    public string PersonName { get; set; }

    private DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    [NameAttribute("Birthday of the Person")]
    public string PersonBDay {
        get {
            return this.bDay.ToShortDateString();
        }
    }
}

...
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class NameAttribute : Attribute {
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public NameAttribute(string name) {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}
```

Is there a possibility to look in my object for all properties which has the attribute `NameAttribute` and get the string form the `Name` property of `NameAttribute`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inspect each property from [`Type.GetProperties`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aky14axb.aspx) and then filter the ones that have the required attribute with the [`MemberInfo.GetCustomAttributes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwc6ew1d.aspx) method.

With a little bit of LINQ, this would look like:

```
var propNameTuples = from property in typeof(Test).GetProperties()
                     let nameAttribute = (NameAttribute)property.GetCustomAttributes
                                (typeof(NameAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault()
                     where nameAttribute != null
                     select new { Property = property, nameAttribute.Name };

foreach (var propNameTuple in propNameTuples)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Property: {0} Name: {1}",
                      propNameTuple.Property.Name, propNameTuple.Name);
}
```

By the way, I also recommend declaring the attribute to be single-use only with `AllowMultiple = false` in the `AttributeUsage` decoration.